# How to add a picture library to a communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, feature-activation, picture-library

I cant find the picture library add-in for a modern communication site. Is there any feature i need to enable?

Answer (score 4):

Few list templates are not available in communication site template. You can enable 'Team Collaboration Lists' in site features to get the picture library templates installed. Navigate to the https://yoursite/_layouts/15/ManageFeatures.aspx and activate the the feature.

Comment: Typical bad Msft ux - no way anyone would know this.

Answer (score 2):

in order to get Pciture Library in SharePoint Online Modern Team/Communication sites follow the below mention steps.

1. Create a new Document Library.
2. Go to Library Settings -> Advance Settings -> and set Allow Management of Content Type to `Yes`.
3. Now in Library setting page, under content types click on `Add from Existing Content type`.
4. Select the `Picture` content type from the list of available content types and click on OK button.
5. Now again in Library setting page, under content type click on `Change new button order and default content type`. Now make `Picture` as default content type and uncheck `Document`.
6. Now go back to Library All Item view. From the `right corner on command bar menu` change the view to `Tiles`.

You are done here. Now you have modern library as `Picture Library`.

Comment: am using an add-in that need a picture library in this scenario it doesnt detect any picture library

Comment: Yeah, adding the content type doesn't work @ThinkB4Code.

Answer (score 1):

Using 3 ways we create a picture libray in the modern SharePoint Online communication/team site:

- By activating site level feature – Team Collaboration Lists
- By adding the picture content type in the library
- By the PnP provisioning template

**PnP provisioning template approach:**

Use the below PnP template and change the picture library template type

**TemplateType="109" and URL**  and the do changes in the column creation section **pnp:Fields** as per your need.

```
    <?xml version=”1.0”?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp=”http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2018/07/ProvisioningSchema”&gt;
<pnp:Preferences Generator=”OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=3.7.1903.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5e633289e95c321a” />
<pnp:Templates ID=”CONTAINER-TEMPLATE-C1181F206BE84C09AAAC4B3CB21FBE32″>
<pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID=”TEMPLATE-C1181F206BE84C09AAAC4B3CB21FBE32″ Version=”1″ Scope=”Web”>
<pnp:Lists>
<pnp:ListInstance Title=”TestPictureLibrary29022020″ TemplateType=”109″ Url=”/TestPictureLibrary29022020″ EnableFolderCreation=”false”>
<pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
<pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID=”0x01″ Default=”true” />
<pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID=”0x0120″ />
</pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
<pnp:Views>
<View Name=”AllItems” DefaultView=”TRUE” Type=”HTML” DisplayName=”All Items” Level=”1″ BaseViewID=”1″ ContentTypeID=”0x”>
<Query>
<OrderBy>
<FieldRef Name=”ID” />
</OrderBy>
</Query>
<ViewFields>
<FieldRef Name=”PictureType” />
<FieldRef Name=”PictureTime” />
<FieldRef Name=”Remarks” />
</ViewFields>
<RowLimit Paged=”TRUE”>30</RowLimit>
</View>
</pnp:Views>
<pnp:Fields>
<Field ID=”{1212a012-1012-4cd9-900b-411f01f2b112}” DisplayName=”Picture Type” Name=”PictureType” Type=”Text”/>
<Field ID=”{3450c003-7607-46de-8345-6c64cd2a3345}” DisplayName=”Picture Time” Name=”PictureTime” Type=”Text”/>
<Field ID=”{70ef44ad-091f-4955-a957-b0fb9b42833b}” DisplayName=”Remarks” Name=”Remarks” Type=”Text”/>
</pnp:Fields>

</pnp:ListInstance>
</pnp:Lists>
</pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
</pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>
```

Use the above XML in the below PnP script:

```
############################Description#######################################################
#The below script will create a list in SharePoint online using PnP template provisioning template.
##############################################################################################

CLS
$userName = "Global-sharepoint2019@globalsharepoint2019.onmicrosoft.com"
$passWord = "YourSPOPassword"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord

Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://globalsharepoint2019.sharepoint.com/sites/CommunicationSiteTest1" -Credentials $cred

Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path "C:\Temp\PnP\SPListPnPProvisioning\ListTemplate.xml"
```

Write-host "Successfully a list has been created in SharePoint online."

**Demo:**

Below is my communication site:

[image: Communication site]

**Execute the above PnP script and verify that Picture library got created inside the communication site:**

[image: Picture Library Got Created in the communication site]

**For details execution please refer the below article:**

[3 ways add a picture library in the communication site – SharePoint Online](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/3-ways-add-a-picture-library-in-the-communication-site-sharepoint-online/)

**Notes:**

- Using this approach without activating any additional feature we can create a picture library.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted it - it is a working code, requesting to look the demo example where I have created the Picture Library using the PnP provisioning XML which is working fine, moreover, PnP is the recommended to way communicate with the SharePoint online object. Using this approach without activating any additional feature we can create picture library.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Create a document library and put pictures in it - call it Pictures if you like! Add the Picture content type to the Doc lib and make it the default so you can see the digital image metadata. Use the Tiles view to see thumbnails of the images or surface the images in an Image Gallery web part on a page.  [We found most of the 3rd party photo albums are refer to picture library instead of document library]

Option 2: Create an Image Gallery web part and add your images to the gallery. You can give the images a title and a caption as you upload them. This creates a Folder called Image Gallery (followed by a bunch of characters) as a sub-folder of the Site Pages library in the Site Assets library. [The default Image Gallery web part is not good enough, can not be show the picture as an album]

Option 3: If the purpose of adding the images is about having a fixed library to use on pages, you can also pre-upload images to a folder or directly to the Site Assets library. That's the default storage space for all images used on modern pages. The images on a page land in a Folder that is dynamically created (along with the Site Assets library) when you use your first image on a page. Each page gets a Folder with the same name as the name of the page (but if you update the page name, the folder name does not change). So the path for page images is Site Assets  (library)> Site Pages (folder) > Name of Page (folder).